# How can I use Python to sort and store Sports Statistics from an Excel file?

Tags: python, excel, sorting, data-structures

I have an excel spreadsheet with sports data - a header row with things like Team, Result, Date, etc, and rows with all of the teams in them (for example, if baseball, the first 162 rows are individual games for one team, then the next 162 are for another, etc).

I'm able to read these into python with XLRD easy enough, but i'm not sure exactly how to store them so that I can easily access information about a specific team. I can use a defaultdict(list) but i'm honestly not too sure how to actually access anything specific.

For example:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
import os.path
import math
import pandas as pd
from xlutils.copy import copy as xl_copy
from collections import defaultdict



result = defaultdict(list)
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("Sample.xls")
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(1)
headers = worksheet.row(0)
for index in range(worksheet.nrows)[1:]:
    for header, col in zip(headers, worksheet.row(index)):
        result[header.value].append(col.value)
```

This stores everything I need in "Result" and the output (if I print it) is like this (example for a 3-row file):

```
Team {'Boston Red Sox','Boston Red Sox','Boston Red Sox'}
Score {'11-4','4-0','5-6'}
Result {'W','W','L'}
```

How can this information be better stored/sorted **by team** in order for me to easily access information pertaining to a specific team? **If I wanted to add up how many victories they had, for example, how would I even do that? Is deafultdict a good use for this situation?

Thanks

Comment: your column headers are fixed? and also can you upload excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have these data:

[image]

You may want to store your data as a `list` of `dictionaries` instead which would look like:

```
data = [{'Team':'Miami Heat', 'Score':'11:4', 'Result':'W'},
        {'Team':'Golden State Warriors', 'Score':'4:0', 'Result':'W'},
        {'Team':'Cleveland Cavaliers', 'Score':'5:6', 'Result':'L'}]
```

You can achieve this with this code:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('Sample.xls')
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

result = []
keys = [v.value.encode('ascii', 'ignore') for v in worksheet.row(0)]

for row_number in range(worksheet.nrows)[1:]:
  row_data = {}
  for col_number, cell in enumerate(worksheet.row(row_number)):
    row_data[keys[col_number]] = cell.value.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
  result.append(row_data)
```

Then with this, you can easily perform operations on array of dictionaries like sorting by team for example using this code:

```
sorted_team = sorted(result, key=lambda k: k['Team'])
```

Suppose you want to scan through each dictionary and get a particular team's score (say *"Miami Heat"* and *"11-4"*), then you can do it with something like:

```
for item in result:
  if item['Team'] == "Miami Heat":
    print item['Score']
```

This is doing it the long way. I am pretty sure that you can simplify this code with `generator expressions` or some other way which I am leaving for you to find out. :)

P.S.
I kinda tweaked your variable names a bit for this code to make them more descriptive.

Comment: Thanks for this - I can visualize this way more easily. 

How do I call a value here? I know it is probably simple, but I just cant picture it. If I want to scan through each one of these dicts, and if one particular team is represented (ex. all dicts containing Miami Heat), pull a specific value out (like points scored), how would I go about that?

Comment: You can get the values out of dictionary with `dict_name["key"]`. So suppose I have a dictionary `dict = {'Team':'Miami Heat', 'Score':'11:4', 'Result':'W'}`, then I can pull out the `team` with `dict['Team']`, `score` with `dict['Score']` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas' [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) method.

This puts your Excel data into a neat dataframe that has the same structure as your Excel table.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("Sample.xls")
```

If you have a datetime column use the option `parse_dates=[datetime_column]`.

Then check if your data has all the correct data types using `df.dtypes` and if you need to change some, use `df[column] = df[column].astype(new_data_type)`.

To sort the dataframe by team:

```
df = df.sort_values("Team").reset_index(drop=True)
```

To select data from a certain team use boolean indexing:

```
df_team = df[df["Team"] == team]
```

If you want to manipulate the filtered data further put a `.copy()` behind the above code to create a new object.

To print the score for that team you can do this:

```
print(df_team["Score"])
```

If the result is long this will omit data, then you can do this instead:

```
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None):
    print(df_team["Score"])
```

Alternatively iterate through the rows, though this is never recommended:

```
for _,row in df_team.iterrows():
    print(row["Score"])
```

Comment: I am still not familiar with python libraries like pandas but this answer of @Khris is much better than mine. It pretty much covers the same thing as I have said but the library abstracts it much better!